# Axios call doesn't return promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, axios

The following `axios` call seems to be fine, but it never returns `promise`, but it returns `undefined`.

```
export function getAllSubmissionDetails() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios
      .get(`/rbac/members/filledForm/getMain/show/1/data/all`, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Pragma': 'no-cache'
        }
      })
      .then((memResponse) => {
        console.log('%%%%%%%');
        console.log(memResponse);
        if (memResponse.data.status == 200) {
          var mem_list = memResponse.data.msg;
          if (mem_list.length > 0) {
            mem_list = _.sortBy(mem_list, "submissionid").reverse()
            dispatch(memIdeaListSuccess(mem_list, null));
            return memResponse
          } else {
            dispatch(memIdeaListFailure("No Submissions", null));
            return memResponse
          }
        } else {
          dispatch(memIdeaListFailure(memResponse.data.msg, null));
          return memResponse
        }

      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch(serviceError(err));
        return Promise.reject(error)
      });
  };
}
```

Comment: Common mistake: you forgot to *return* the promise: `return axios.get(`...

Comment: Also you can just `return memResponse` once at the bottom of your `then` callback as all branches lead to returning the `memResponse` anyway

Answer (score 3):

You aren't returning the value returned by axios and hence and undefined returned value

```
export function getAllSubmissionDetails(){
                return (dispatch) => {
                        // return value here
                        return axios.get(`/rbac/members/filledForm/getMain/show/1/data/all`, {
                        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json','Pragma': 'no-cache' }
                      })
                        .then((memResponse) => {
                            console.log('%%%%%%%');
                            console.log(memResponse);
                            if(memResponse.data.status == 200){
                                var mem_list = memResponse.data.msg;
                                if(mem_list.length>0) {
                                    mem_list = _.sortBy(mem_list,"submissionid").reverse()
                                    dispatch(memIdeaListSuccess(mem_list,null));
                                    return memResponse
                                } else {
                                    dispatch(memIdeaListFailure("No Submissions",null));
                                    return memResponse 
                                }
                            }else{
                                dispatch(memIdeaListFailure(memResponse.data.msg,null));
                                return memResponse
                            }

                        })
                        .catch((err) => {dispatch(serviceError(err)); return Promise.reject(error)});
                    };
              }
```

Comment: Better vote as duplicate than to answer...